# jqTransform Cancel Button

Tags: jqtransform

I'm trying to get jqTransform to work on a form.
I want to give the user the option to cancel the new forma and return to the page they just came from.

I've read in numerous threads that jqTransform actually transforms the html, so my onclick() is probably not going to work.  The jqTransform demo that comes in the zip file actually has a Cancel button on it but doesn't show how to make it work. What my button code looks like is this:

This identical code works on a form that is not using jqTransform.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with jquery event handler

```
 $("#btncancel").click(function() {
       document.location.href='index.php';
 })
```

btncancel is cancel button ID.